# Dependency Injection e Specification Pattern

Tags: c#

Boa noite.

Será que alguém pode me dar uma ajuda para entender essa questão do Specification Pattern e a Injeção de Dependência?

Por exemplo:

Na minha camada de serviço eu preciso verificar se o usuário preencheu algumas informações e se esta informação está dentro das condições esperadas do sistema (ex.: num blog, o usuário preencher o título e o título possui entre três e sessenta caracteres?).

Poderia muito bem fazer algo no método para verificar essa regra, mas poderiam haver várias regras e ficaria um método extenso e feio para isso. Além de quebrar as regras do SOLID.

Ok, posso implementar uma Specification Patter básica pra isso. Mas, o objeto de serviço (ex.: Blogs.PostService) teria que receber como parâmetro o Repositório e mais os Specifications, certo?

Mas se eu tenho um método para consulta, um para salvar, um para excluir... o objeto de serviço terá que receber um Specification para cada situação (já que as regras são diferentes para cada situação)? Ou seja, teria que ter um construtor como:

```
public PostService(IRepositorio rep, ISpecificationSave ss, SpecificationGet g, ISpecificationDelete sd) { 
      // do things... 
}
```

Espero que a questão não esteja abstrata demais... Quero entender como eu posso relacionar essas duas técnicas sem fazer muita bagunça...

Agradeço pelas orientações desde já.